# How to turn off toggle switch when it is on using selenium webdriver with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have this little toggle here, I need to switch it off if it's on

[image: toggle]

This is how the html look like when it's on:
The inner div is for the white circle inside the green, but i can click wherever under the green square.

[image]

I usually use CroPath for finding the XPath so I get this:

[image]

Usually, I always use

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,path).click()
```

For clicking buttons and it always work, but for this one I have use the XPath and CSS selector to find the element and it didn't work. Any idea how I can click this toggle?

For reference, this is how the button looks like when it's off and the html behind it:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe use should use click for inner div object, I mean like :

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,path).find_element_by_tag_name('div').click()
```

This may work.